# Cannot install Lubuntu on Compaq, tried everything

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, lubuntu, compaq

I'm using an old Compaq CQ10-100 with very sluggish performance so I've decided to install lubuntu 14.4.05 LTS today.

Since it is only a netbook, I don't have a CD drive and have had to use the USB method.

After formatting the USB and extracting the ISO into the USB so that there's nothing else on it, I booted my computer and selected for it to boot from the USB rather than the hard drive.

I  expected to see some kind of installation screen but instead I see nothing but a black screen with a white blinking cursor at the top.

I only have the installation files as were burned on the USB stick so i don't understand why it wouldn't work.

After opening it within windows xp through wubi it just asks me what i want to do after booting, so guess it's no help at all. The second time i tried opening wubi it told me that a previous installation has to be removed (what previous installation!?)

when at the black screen with the white cursor, I can't type anything, no keys work at all. I just have to press the power key and start windows XP again.

A shame but i've spent all of today looking for solutions to this problem and haven't found any for my case.

System specs:
Compaq CQ10-100
Windows XP
Intel Atom
1GB DDR2 RAM

Comment: Doing it from Windows Rufus is the recommended tool: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows In your case the option shown in the screenshots is the one you need, MBR/BIOS. Alternatively you can use the `dd` option. Do NOT use wubi.

Comment: Extracting the contents of an ISO to a flash drive is not the same as [creating a bootable media](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) Assuming your ISO image [is bootable](http://superuser.com/questions/440035/how-can-i-check-whether-an-iso-image-is-bootable) which it is if you downloaded it from approved sources.

Comment: Wubi is a discontinued project. Don't use it. On really old computers you could also consider using really light weight Linux flavors like for example Puppy Linux, which is focused on older hardware.